# PopupWindow hidden below status bar. Whats the solution?

Tags: java, android, statusbar, popupwindow

In my App i have two popupWindows. I open them both like..

```
aboutView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_about, null);
aboutWindow = new PopupWindow(aboutView, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
aboutWindow.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.lay_main), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

Both layouts are set to match_parent, where one of them opens just fine.
The second starts on the screens top, hidden below the Android status bar.

The reason must be within the layouts itself.
When i copy the good and just rename it..it shows up just fine.
When i change the content (add image views etc..), it's screwd up.

Is there a known reason?

**EDIT:**
I just figured out that i have an ScrollView in my layout..as soon as i remove that or change it to e.g. an RelativeView, thats when it slips under the status bar.